# core data subclass with collectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uicollectionviewcell

In my collectionView based app i want to cache the last 100 cells loaded, and i think best way for me is to work with core data.
I already have a custom class for UICollectionViewCell, and obviously all the cells are objects of this class. it's look kind of like this:

```
@interface Cell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *cellFacebookId;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *cellMail;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *cellAddId;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *cellCategory;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *cellBackImg;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *titleBarImage;

@end
```

Now I've created an entity named Cell, with same attributes. can i create a NSManagedObject subclass that will replace my original "Cell" class and still use it as UICollectionViewCell custom class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a subclass of NSManagedObject as a UICollectionView cell. It has to be a subclass of UICollectionViewCell. Besides UICollectionView reuses cells by caching them.

Comment: every time my app loads it's connecting to a remote database and importing data, i want to minimize the revived data by caching last used cells, how can i get to data cached by UICollectionView before i define a data source?

Comment: You don't need to cache cells. It is enough if you save the data you load from the web service. Just save it in core data and next time you open the app it can load the already available dataset. Cells are just a visual representation of your data. UICollectionView does not cache your data.

Comment: yes, that's what i wanted to do, so you say the best way for me is to keep using my Cell custom class, and subclass another one with NSManagedObject for data core? even that I'll have 2 copies of every cell on memory?

Comment: Not exactly. You create one subclass of UICollectionViewCell for displaying your data and one (or more) subclass of NSManagedObject for storing your data in CoreData. After fetching your data you create your core data objects and put them in the database. You retrieve them when you want to present your UICollectionView and assign the appropriate properties to the properties of your UICollectionView subclass.